# Is it possible to achieve this type of effect in Xamarin's progress bar?

Tags: xamarin.android, android-progressbar

[image]

Attached a photo. I want to create a progress bar that is continuously running in this form. The progress bar of the Xamarin form gradually fills up according to the value. I want to make a progress bar that keeps running after setting the start and end lengths.

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/9776

Comment: It is a little confusing, you are tagging xamarin.android but talking about xamarin forms. You can try the solution here, should work fine:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fa381565-a05e-4bbc-be4c-681141c255be/is-there-the-indeterminate-attribute-for-the-progressbar-in-xamarinforms?forum=xamarinforms

Comment: Did you want to a rectangle in the progress bar and move it when the process changed?